# How can I make the entire code appear?

Tags: math-mode

There is no compile error but the following code isn't being displayed in the PDF. There is just a blank space in the PDF.

```
\begin{aligned}
a_i + a_{i+1} + a_{i+2} + \dots + a_{i + 99} &= 100\\ \\
\text{But, for any }j, \\
a_{j} +a_{j+1} + \dots + a_{j+5} &\leq 6 \\ \\
\therefore (a_i + a_{i+1} + \dots + a_{i+5}) + (a_{i+6} + \dots + a_{i+11}) + \\ \dots + (a_{i+96}+ \dots + a_{i+100} + a_{i+101}) &\leq 17\times6\\ \\
\implies (a_i + a_{i+1} + \dots + a_{i+5}) + (a_{i+6} + \dots + a_{i+11}) + \\ \dots + (a_{i+96}+ \dots + a_{i} + a_{i+1}) &\leq 102\\
\implies (a_i + a_{i+1} + \dots +a_{98} + a_{99}) + a_{i} + a_{i+1}) &\leq 102\\
\implies 100 + a_i + a_{i+1} &\leq 2\\
\implies a_i + a_{i+1} &\leq 2\\ \\
\text{If any one pair has a sum less than 2, it means that some other pair has a sum greater than 2. Since, this is not possible, it implies that all pairs have a sum divisible by 2.} \\
\text{Similarly,}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
```

Comment: I'm not sure precisely what you are trying to achieve, but aligned is definitely NOT the right environment.  align might do, especially if you use \intertext or \shortintetext (from mathtools).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Can you elaborate on what you mean ? I get an error when I use align.

Comment: aligned is supposed to be used inside another math environment.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Can you give me some more information. I'm new to this and don't know much about environments.

Comment: You do know that every package comes with documentation?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Can you tell me how align and aligned are meant to be used ?

Comment: First, some math is built into LaTeX, but the rest comes from packages line amsmath and mathtools.  The align envirionment is like equation or \[ ... \] in that it starts and ends math mode (display style).  The aligned environment is used inside an equation to handle things like the contents of \left( ... \right).

Answer (score 2):

You can move the \therefore and \implies further to the left using additional & symbols and possibly `flalign`.  Note, every second & symbol produces a large gap.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a_i + a_{i+1} + a_{i+2} + \dots + a_{i + 99} &= 100\\
\shortintertext{But, for any $j$,}
a_{j} +a_{j+1} + \dots + a_{j+5} &\leq 6\\
\therefore
(a_i + a_{i+1} + \dots + a_{i+5}) + (a_{i+6} + \dots + a_{i+11}) +  \notag\\
  \dots + (a_{i+96}+ \dots + a_{i+100} + a_{i+101}) &\leq 17\times6\\
\implies (a_i + a_{i+1} + \dots + a_{i+5}) + (a_{i+6} + \dots + a_{i+11}) +  \notag\\
 \dots + (a_{i+96}+ \dots + a_{i} + a_{i+1}) &\leq 102\\
\implies (a_i + a_{i+1} + \dots +a_{98} + a_{99}) + a_{i} + a_{i+1}) &\leq 102\\
\implies 100 + a_i + a_{i+1} &\leq 2\\
\implies a_i + a_{i+1} &\leq 2
\end{align}
If any one pair has a sum less than 2, it means that some other pair has a sum greater than 2. Since, this is not possible, it implies that all pairs have a sum divisible by 2.

Similarly,
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: I am using the document class book and align is giving me an error.

Comment: What sort of error?  Obviously it works fine for me.

Comment: Figured out the error. Align, unlike aligned should not be enclosed within dollar signs. Thanks.